# fontspec changes the size of the letter boxes

Tags: fonts, fontspec

`fontspec` changes the size of the letter boxes. Compare

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\Huge\fbox{S}\fbox{F}
\end{document}
```

with the same code but `\usepackage{fontspec}` not commented out. In the figure, the left is without `fontspec` and the right is with it.
[image]

Is there a way to have them same size as without the `fontspec` package?

Comment: Btw, this causes problems with `chemfig` package in alignment. In particular, when one wants to draw (`tikz`) nodes under atoms (letters) their vertical alignment goes wrong.

Comment: An additional observation: The behavior occurs under both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Mico Yes, but XeLaTeX says both characters have the same height (with `\fontcharht\font`).

Comment: The sizes of the capital letters take into account the overshoot, which is an error, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg Meaning it is a font error as opposed to a `fontspec` issue proper?

Comment: @cfr TeX considers the height and depth of the contents; if a character advertises a larger height than another, then the two `\fbox` commands will give different results.

Comment: @egreg So the different heights result from the font erroneously specifying a greater height for 'S' than for 'F'?

Comment: @cfr Exactly. Not only Latin Modern, by the way.

Comment: @egreg Indeed. I just thought it was worth clarifying this since I would not have understood this from your original comment if I did not already know various things about TeX's use of fonts. (Not as much as you, obviously, but more than I know about most aspects of TeX.)

Comment: Unlike TFM fonts, the height and depth of the glyphs in TTF/OTF fonts are taken from their bounding boxes and are not explicitly set by the font designer, so there is no way for the engine to identify overshots and the likes.

Comment: Loading `fontspec` switiches the default font to latin modern from computer modern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to bad font design, in my opinion. Instead of letting `S` overshoot its bounding box, the font developers decided to define a bounding box that vertically covers the whole inked area and has some sidebearings, as it becomes apparent when setting the parameter `\fboxsep` to zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\Huge
\fbox{S}\fbox{F}\fbox{f}\fbox{\itshape f}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that both sidebearings of the italic `f` are negative, whereas only the right sidebearing is negative for the upright `f`.

I don't know if this is an inherent limitation of OpenType fonts or just careless design: in a well crafted Roman font, all uppercase letters should have the same height and zero depth. Letters may overshoot the bounding box, but this overshoot should *not* be taken into account for determining the height and depth.

If you want a “capital letter box” macro, you can use an "I" as a model:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\cfbox}{\fbox{\vphantom{I}\smash{#1}}}

\begin{document}


\Huge
\cfbox{S}\cfbox{F}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the information and the hack solution! Im still interested, why is this phenomenom observed only with `fontspec` ?

Comment: @Mappi If you don't load `fontspec`, the fonts selected are the same you load with `pdflatex`, that are properly designed.

Comment: Just realized that the same thing happens with numbers in `mathrm` and `mathsf` environments.

Comment: Btw, doesn't this mean that with `fontspec` fonts are not really typeset on the same baseline? Isn't this super bad?

Comment: @Mappi Yes, they are. The first picture shows that the overshoot at the bottom is considered as depth. The bottom curve of the `S` should be below the baseline and it is.